# ASP.NET Web.config CustomErrors a paginas .aspx

Tags: asp.net

por favor su colaboración con el siguiente caso: Tengo un sistema web en asp.net (.net 1.1 VS2003), en el web.config tengo el customErrors (On) a una pagina genérica de errores, bueno el problema es el siguiente: Si al defautlRedirect le asigno una pagina .htm funciona con normalidad, pero si le asigno a una página .aspx no funciona, simplemente muestra la pantalla amarilla como si el CustomErrores estuviese en Off. Alguien sabe a que se debe esto? Saludos.

Comment: La idea es que se redireccione a un archivo .aspx para que muestre un mensaje genérico y al mismo tiempo capturar la excepción y guardarla y notificar.

Comment: Revisa tu página .aspx si no tiene algún problema, se puede compartir para revisarla?

Comment: Pos jejejejeje que vergüenza, tenia una excepción en la página a la que se re-direccionaba.

Comment: No te preocupes @RSillerico, en ocasiones nos sucede jeje, al menos resolviste el problema.

Comment: Pos ya no tengo el error pero si tengo un problema, en el pageload de la pagina .aspx a la que  se re-direcciona, enm el page load tengo 
      Exception e = Server.GetLastError() 
Pero siempre me retorna NULL, hay alguna configuración extra que se debe hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Si al `defaultRedirect` le asigno una pagina .htm funciona con
>   normalidad, pero si le asigno a una página .aspx no funciona

No es que funcione con .html y con .aspx no, me parece que el problema es la página .aspx, te sugiero habilites `mode="On"` para que puedas ver cual es el problema en tu .aspx:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="[tu url]"
              mode="On">
 ...
 ...
</customErrors>
```